# Lua: How to deserialize a string to a multidimensional table?

Tags: lua, deserialization

I'm currently stuck with this function:
I have a function which takes a multidimensional table and converts it to a string. The formatting is just as tables in the lua code.
Now I have to reverse it - the goal is to get the same multidimensional table back. 
I have found this function for getting the string from the table - what would be the opposite?

```
    toReturn = "{"
    for ind, val in pairs(tbl) do
        if type(val) == "table" then
            toReturn = toReturn .. (type(ind) == "number" and "" or ind .. "=") .. tableAsString(val) .. ","
        else
            local newVal
            if type(val) == "string" then
                newVal = "\"" .. val .. "\""
            else
                newVal = val
            end
            toReturn = toReturn .. (type(ind) == "number" and "" or ind .. "=") .. newVal .. ","
        end
    end

    toReturn = toReturn:sub(1,-2) .. "}" -- remove trailing "," and close table

    return toReturn
end
```

Comment: Your title seems to contradict the question body, do you need assistance deserializing the serialized table? you can use `load(serialized Table)()`, or `loadstring(serialized Table)()` depending on your version of lua.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!! I really didn't think that it could be that easy!

Comment: Consider the corner cases. The string may contain the character ```"``` or newlines, tabs, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nifim's answer works perfectly and my problem is solved.
The table can be read with

```
loadstring(serializedTable)()
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your table also may contain strings with the string `"`, newlines, tabs etc.
I wrote this function for me which takes care of this:

```lua
local function buildLiteral(value, tableAsVararg, buildedLiteralsCache)
    if not buildedLiteralsCache then
        buildedLiteralsCache = {}
    end

    local resultStr = nil

    if value == nil then
        resultStr = "nil"
    else
        if not buildedLiteralsCache[value] then
            local t = type(value)
            local str = nil

            if t == "boolean" or t == "number" then
                str = tostring(value)
            elseif t == "string" then
                str = "\"" .. string.gsub(string.gsub(string.gsub(string.gsub(string.gsub(value, "\\", "\\\\"), "\"", "\\\""), "\r", "\\r"), "\n", "\\n"), "\t", "\\t") .. "\""
            elseif t == "table" then
                if tableAsVararg then
                    str = ""

                    if table.getn(value) >= 1 then
                        for _, v in ipairs(value) do
                            str = str .. buildLiteral(v, false, buildedLiteralsCache) .. ", "
                        end

                        str = string.sub(str, 1, string.len(str) - 2)
                    end
                else
                    str = "{"

                    for k, v in pairs(value) do
                        str = str .. "[" .. buildLiteral(k, false, buildedLiteralsCache) .. "]=" .. buildLiteral(v, false, buildedLiteralsCache) .. ", "
                    end

                    if string.len(str) > 1 then
                        str = string.sub(str, 1, string.len(str) - 2)
                    end

                    str = str .. "}"
                end
            else
                error("buildLiteral called with unsupported type='" .. t .. "'")
            end

            buildedLiteralsCache[value] = str
        end

        resultStr = buildedLiteralsCache[value]
    end

    return resultStr
end
```

You can then load the table again using `loadstring(str)()`